How do you utilize a voltage signal from a subcircuit when developing a larger circuit?
I am trying to understand how circuits are built.  In my experience learning about circuits, I have learned all about analysis techniques for circuits that start with a complete circuit and ask, "what is the voltage/current through X component?" (namely, a resistor, capacitor, or inductor).
E.g. Suppose, I have just calculated the voltage \$v_C\$ across the capacitor for this circuit:

(Image source: Electronics Tutorials - Series RLC Circuit Analysis)
I understand how to make calculations for this type of circuit, but the question then stands:
"What will I do with this signal?"
If you add more components, the properties of the original circuit will be changing.  The only exception to this is if you simply bias \$v_C\$ with a DC voltage and pass it as input to an amplifier, but this assumes \$v_C\$ is a small signal.
So my question is, in general, is it safe to assume that signals that are calculated in this way (which are framed as this type of question) are indeed small signals?
Or...
If this is not the case, are there ways to iteratively develop circuits so that you can avoid the ramifications of next stages of circuit building completely changing the "base" circuit (in this case the base would be the circuit containing the signal you wish to work with).
If this is also not the case, is developing larger circuits simply reliant on a combination of experience and deep knowledge of patterns  (and the intuition that comes from these)?  And then performing analysis to verify the final product.

I understand my question may be a bit ill-defined, so I'd like to add that I'm primarily seeking to develop the electrical engineer's perspective and gain insight into what the process looks like when the question is posed:  "How can we develop a circuit to carry out X functionality?"

Like many engineering questions, the answer is "it depends". In the circuit shown, I wouldn't say Vc is a super-useful quantity as it's a phase shifted, scaled version of the input and there are ways to get a higher "quality" version depending on what you need it for. Just for an example, if you're using it to trigger the gate of a thyristor, there are better ways to go about it since Vc is dependent on the values of R, L, and C which are themselves dependent (in the real world) on temperature, frequency, etc, in addition to their own component tolerances which could exceed +/- 20%.

This a pretty broad question, but I'll address a couple of points. First, I think you have a misconception about "small signal" analysis.
The circuit you show is entirely linear (at least with ideal parts it is). So small signal vs. large signal is not different. What matters if you choose to use the voltage vc(t) is what the circuit you connect it do does to vc(t). For example, if you connect it to the input of a CMOS op-amp the effect will primarily be input capacitance and it will be like you increased the value of the capacitor. A resistive input load will have a different effect. Some circuits may look inductive at the input even if they have no inductors. And anything in between. If you are making something like an analog filter, with no amplifiers between stages, the interactions are quite complex, but it's all linear. A signal of 1mV and 1V behave the same, just scaled. This is not to say that creating a design is necessarily easy, of course. Here is a textbook ("Synthesis of Passive Networks", Guillemin) example of a circuit designed to have a specific impedance function:

This is too complex to "design" by fiddling with part values in a simulator.
Where small vs. large signal come into play is when you have nonlinear elements such as active element (BJTs, MOSFETs etc) or things like diodes, inductors that saturate, capacitors that have huge voltage coefficient etc. With small signal analysis we do a large signal analysis of something like a transistor amplifier and then use a linearized analysis for a small signal about the operating point that was found in the previous calculation. When the signal is small enough, even a gnarly curve looks like a straight line with a fixed slope. That allows us to find approximate analytical solutions and to get valuable insights to situations where an exact analytical solution is impossible.
Of course, modern simulation software can analyze nonlinear circuits directly, at least as far as looking at it from the outside appears. Inside is another matter you'll run into it if you spend much time with simulators.

As to your general question, a typical case is where the output of one block has a defined effect on the previous block. At low frequencies, that result is often that it has negligible effect or there is a nice predictable load that is easy to account for. For example, an instrumentation amplifier may feed an anti-aliasing low-pass filter and that may feed an ADC. Each input would typically have a very high impedance and each output a very low impedance, so connecting them does little to the signal. In some cases, there might be a controlled impedance like 50Ω (resistive) that is also straightforward to deal with (you design that block to have the specified load, the next block to present that load, and any internal complexities of the next block are unimportant).
You might even say that, in general, what encourages us to partition and analyze circuits in blocks is that the interactions are generally only significant in the direction of signal flow.

Seems like examples are asked for.
In the example RLC series circuit, OP recognizes that \$V_c\$ sees the voltage generator's DC full output. If the voltage generator's frequency is very high, \$V_c\$ is attenuated. In this respect, Vc has the form of a low-pass filter.
Once you comprehend this basic circuit, how current flows at various frequency, its DC response, voltage distribution across each component for frequencies from 0 Hz up to many megahertz, you might recognize it in circuit diagrams like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I have added Rload in parallel with the capacitor of OP's series circuit. But the basic series RLC circuit is visible (I hope: R1, ferrite bead, C1). Functionally, the ferrite bead L1 has a tiny internal resistance (R1=0.1 ohm). It acts in concert with C1 to serve as a low-pass filter as outlined above. Nearly all of V1's DC voltage is to be delivered to Rload. However, isolation is required at high frequency so that disturbances created by the module cannot reach and disturb V1 (or disturb other circuits that V1 might power).
Another reason for isolation might involve noise or ripple generated by V1 that should not reach the module.
This is only one example where a textbook RLC circuit finds application in real circuits. Low-pass filtering is just one example of RLC. Once you understand deeply how inductors, capacitors and resistors interact at various frequencies, you can more easily analyze circuit function.
